# Use a Mac to create a CSR for another server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, mac-osx, bluemix

I have a website hosted on Bluemix.

I want to set up an SSL certificate, I am following this guide: https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/09/28/ssl-certificates-bluemix-custom-domains/

I placed an order for a Thawte 123 certificate, and I am at the stage where I need to paste my CSR in a text box. The instructions from the Thawte help center says to generate this "from the server".

However, I don't have access to the bluemix server itself, nor ssh access. Instead, according to the article I linked to, I have a web UI to upload both the private key and the certificate. Which, I assume, is the workaround to this issue.

I am on a Mac. Googling the issue, all the articles I found (ex: https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=INFO2989 ) assumed I want to create a certificate for a Mac server. But here what I want is to create the certificate request from a mac, but for a third party server!

How do I generate a valid CSR for Thawte, from a Mac (not server)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not matter where you generate the CSR. As long as you have entered the correct FQDN and use the correct private key for your CSR everything should work.

Edit:
Generating a CSR on OSX works the same as on a Linux host. If you do not have openSSL installed on your Mac you can install it with brew.

If you do have openSSL installed you can for example use the following commands in Terminal:

```
# Generate private key
openssl genrsa -out example.key 2048
# Generate CSR
openssl req -new -sha256 -key example.key -out example.csr
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I understood from other answers. The only part I am missing is not the "if" but the "how"?

Comment: @nute : Sorry, I've misunderstood the question and have updated my answer.